# What is "." in Python?

Tags: python

The Python language specification includes `.` in its list of delimiters:

https://docs.python.org/3.5/reference/lexical_analysis.html#delimiters

and later refers to `.` as the "attribute reference" operator (though "operator" is implied here):

https://docs.python.org/3.5/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence

In some other languages I've (possibly incorrectly) called `.` the member access operator.  In Java, for example, it's referred to in the documentation as a separator or punctuator.

Is there an authoritative reference on what exactly `.` is, is called, and does in Python?  Python 3 answer preferable, but if it's defined in 2, I guess I'm happy with that as well.

Comment: [This essay](https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.2.3/descrintro/) is *quite* old, but much of what it discusses is still relevant now, in both 2.7 and 3.x.

Comment: Attribute lookups with `.` are described higher up in the second page you linked to: https://docs.python.org/3.5/reference/expressions.html#attribute-references

Comment: The relevant AST class is `ast.Attribute`.

Comment: Are you just looking for an official "name" of the `.` operator?  If that's the case, there _might_ be an official name, but I don't know it and I've been coding in python for quite a while without that knowledge :-).  I think that the most common "vernacular" term that I hear is "dot".  e.g. If I were speaking the expression `foo.bar`, I'd say "foo dot bar"... This might be irrelevant though because if I were speaking the expression `+42`, I'd say "plus forty-two" rather than "Unary addition operator forty-two"

Comment: I usually just say "dot"